# Why does the methods doesn't compile

Tags: java, java-8

I have a multi catch exception block with a methods that doesn't compile , there's no inhertance relation between the two classes 
I still not able to define the rule behind this error ,this my code :

```
class MyException extends RuntimeException {
    public void log() {
        System.out.println("Logging MyException");
    }
}

class MyException2 extends RuntimeException {
    public void log() {
        System.out.println("Logging MyException2");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new MyException();
        } catch(MyException | MyException2 ex){
            ex.log(); // this doesn't compile !
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because the two classes have a method with the same name does not mean you can call that method and have the right thing happen.

To make this work, you *must* either catch the two exception types separately or have them implement a common interface containing the `log()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement custom common interface, containing `log()` method:

```java
public interface LoggingException {
    void log();
}
```

And implement your exceptions from it:

```java
public class MyException extends RuntimeException implements LoggingException {
    public void log() {
        System.out.println("Logging MyException");
    }
}
```

Note: it is not a common practice to add custom functionality to exceptions, especially logging. You might want to use logger externally and do something like this:

```java
catch(Exception e) {
    log.error("error happened", e);
}
```